# How to use one StreamWriter to write to multiple underlying streams?

Tags: c#, azure, stream, compression, gzipstream

I am writing text to a `System.IO.StreamWriter`.

The underlying stream (specified in `new StreamWriter(underlyingStream)`) writes to a remote file. (I don't think its type is relevant, but for completeness' sake I'll mention it's a microsoft azure `CloudBlobStream underlyingStream`).

Now, I wanted to extend this by also writing an additional compressed file with the same content, but by using `GZipOutputStream compressedUnderlyingStream` between the `StreamWriter` and a second `CloudBlobStream`.

I was looking for a way to specify both of the `CloudBlobStream`s as underlying streams of the `StreamWriter`. But I could not find a way. Does there exist some stream type that can combine two underlying streams? Or how can I otherwise approach this? Note I want everything to stay as streams to minimize amount of data in memory.

```
//disregard lack of using statements for this example's sake
CloudBlobStream blobStream = blob.OpenWrite();
CloudBlobStream compressedBlobStream = compressedBlob.OpenWrite();
GZipOutputStream compressorStream = new GZipOutputStream(compressedBlobStream);
//I make the streamwriter here for the regular blob,
///but how could I make the same streamwriter also write to the compressedBlob at the same time?
TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(blobStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: There is no such standard `Stream` implementation, you need to make your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't think of one off the top of my head, but it would be trivial to write your own:

```
class MultiStream : Stream
{
    private List<Stream> streams;

    public Streams(IEnumerable<Stream> streams)
    {
        this.streams = new List<Stream>(streams);
    }

    ...

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        foreach(Stream stream in streams)
            stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    ...
}
```

---

**Edit:** Thank you to [tenbits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2436109) who has completed the [implementation of the above class](https://gist.github.com/tenbits/ac5441e84b7983e0e17f39be172e87f9). Because it is neither my work nor something I have personally tested, I have only provided a link and will leave the original answer unchanged.

Comment: Thanks -- Any thoughts on what to do with the other properties though, such as `Length` and `Position`, I suppose they can be different depending on the kind of underlying stream?

Comment: @DavidS. Maybe show the minimum of of all lengths, and have a relative position depending on each starting position

Comment: yeah maybe.. as a private implementation I suppose I could get away with throwing exception on those two properties as long as they're not used by the other streams or by me

Comment: @DavidS. I wouldn't want to throw exceptions on those properties, since they could be called by StreamWriter/Reader. I would just return "safe" values, like the minimum length of all streams. That would guarantee the position would never go past the end of a stream. Keeping track of the position would be trickier though.

Comment: Just in case somebody would need the implementation: https://gist.github.com/tenbits/ac5441e84b7983e0e17f39be172e87f9